# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing in php

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

In my web application, try to pass data to another domain with ajax call. But it shows error like `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/auth/webschool/test.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

My ajax code is,

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://example.com/auth/webschool/test.php",
                data: {username: "abcd",password:"abcd"},
                 dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: So update your PHP file to send a relevant `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put this line on test.php, hope it will work

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Waleed Ahmed. It works.